# Given a pandas dataframe with three columns how can I groupby one columns and return the sub-dataframe rows as a dict

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, group-by, aggregation

Input: pd.DataFrame, e.g.

```
input = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [
         'asset_one',
         'asset_one',
         'asset_two',         
     ],
    'B': [
        'item_one',
        'item_two',
        'item_three'
    ],
    'C': ['feature_a', 'feature_b', 'feature_c']
})
```

How can I get the desired output:

```
output = {
      'asset_one': {'item_one': 'feature_a', 'item_two': 'feature_b'},
      'asset_two': {'item_three': 'feature_c'},
}
```

In other words, I would like to grouby by the first column and return ta dict whose keys are the groups and whose values are dict with the "sub-dataframe" after the groupby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use lambda function with `zip` and `dict` in [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html):

```
out = input.groupby('A').apply(lambda x: dict(zip(x.B, x.C))).to_dict()
print (out)
{'asset_one': {'item_one': 'feature_a', 'item_two': 'feature_b'}, 
 'asset_two': {'item_three': 'feature_c'}}
```

Or use `dict comprehension`:

```
out = {n: dict(zip(x.B, x.C)) for n, x in input.groupby('A')}
print (out)
{'asset_one': {'item_one': 'feature_a', 'item_two': 'feature_b'}, 
 'asset_two': {'item_three': 'feature_c'}}
```

Comment: Thank you, what would you use if you were to compare w.r.t performance or readbility/pythonic? Note that the input is a dataframe created just to exploit its groupby, the original data structure is a list of instances of a custom class that have the three columns as instance variables

Comment: @LucaM - I think best test, but second solution should be prefered in my opinion, because not necessary convert to dictionary in last step.

Answer (score 3):

Let us use dict comprehension

```
{k: g['C'].to_dict() for k, g in df.set_index('B').groupby('A')}
```

---

```
{'asset_one': {'item_one': 'feature_a', 'item_two': 'feature_b'},
 'asset_two': {'item_three': 'feature_c'}}
```

Comment: Thank you, I prefer @jezrael solutions as I find them more readable